# OPC UA .NET Client - Get OPCUA Node ID using browse path

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

I'm working with the [OPC Foundation's .NET Standard stack](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandardLibrary) and need to get a node ID using its browse path.  With the Python FreeOPCUA implementation I've been using, it is easily done like this:

`obj = root.get_child(["0:Objects", "2:MyObject"])`

I'm just looking for the equivalent of that and haven't found a set of documentation that's been helpful so far.  I can browse the entire root node using code from one of the sample applications.  I want to avoid that overhead since I know exactly where the node I'm looking for is located and just need its ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds` service.

It looks like there's an example of how to call it in the `ClientUtils` class [in one of the examples here](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandardLibrary/blob/cd4173aa95abd296578b976be67485c299473a70/SampleApplications/Samples/ClientControls/ClientUtils.cs#L697-L789).

Comment: Thanks!  That does exactly what I need.